# Db2 proper syntax for adding a constraint and a primary key

Tags: sql, db2

I got the following SQL command from a DDL of a table in SQL Server. I need to set the same in a db2 database:

```
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table"
ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_BLA_DIM" PRIMARY KEY "FRR_BLUR_ID"
```

I have been trying to set it up but I don't know the right syntax and it show different errors. Can someone help me with the right syntax here? Appreciate it.

Comment: Try [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) with ADD `unique-constraint` clause. Column name(s) must be in the round brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE <schema.table_name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>
PRIMARY KEY (<column_name>)
```

Comment: Thank you Lennart yes I realize some hours later in some other post

Comment: @Mike If you think this answer is correct, accept it.